# Launch Google Hangout on Android from website

Tags: android, google-hangouts

On my website i setup a Hangout button using the following code.

```
gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-hangout', {
                                'render': 'createhangout',
                                'invites': "[{ id : 'XXXXX', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]"
                            });
```

This code works perfectly fine on any desktop computer, but when i click the button from my android phone i get the message

> 'This call is already over'.

Has anyone run into this issue before?